# MFMailComposeViewController recipient hide behind Sender bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have MFMailComposeViewController in my apps and recipient hide behind sender bar.How can I make it visible and show properly?

[image]

```
- (void)bottomBtnClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
        NSString *emailTitle = @"Feedback";
        // Email Content
        NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi Support,\rI have some feedback here:-\r"];
        // To address
        NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"admin@xxx.com"];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
        [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
        [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

        // Present mail view controller on screen
        [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: try to embed the controller in a navigation controller before presenting it

Comment: Hi @CZ54, I have tried but seems like does not work. Any idea or sample can show me? Thanks!